# The specified task executable location ... is invalid

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin. I'm having a problem with deployment. The project builds successfully but then I get an error message:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2):
>   Error MSB6004: The specified task executable location
>   "C:\android\sdk\tools\zipalign.exe" is invalid. (MSB6004) (FirstApp)
>   ". " Deployment failed. Packaging failed ".

I'm not sure what the problem is or what to do to resolve this. Please help.

Comment: An obvious investigation would be to see if the zipalign tool exists at that location, and if so if it can be invoked from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Because of a new Android version, the zipalign got switched from directory.  See over [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/61585)

Currently, I saw they updated Xamarin with a fix for this. You should try to update Xamarin first. [Version 5.1.2](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_5.1/xamarin.studio_5.1/) fixes this: "Fixes a regression introduced by Android SDK Tools r23 and Android Build-tools r20 that changed the path of the zipalign tool."

Answer (score 1):

This solution just worked for me:

You need to copy

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\zipalign.exe
```

not in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools
```

but in

```
C:\Users\yourfolder\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools
```

Also see:

ApkClean 0.9.02

https://code.google.com/p/apkclean/downloads/detail?name=ApkClean-0.9.02.zip&can=2&q=

:)